# eSim support check

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I just need to detect if the device supports esim devices. I will not add new data for eSIM through the application (only by qr code). is there some way to check this without generating a certificate to support esim? It's too long to wait and I don't need all its functionality. I want to check with my device or not.

What I have tried:

CTCellularPlanProvisioning().supportsCellularPlan() —— always returns false (as I understand it, this is just because of the Provisioning certificate)

I also tried to get the current CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology operators, but this also fails to quickly get data about the type of eSim card.

Is there a method / api from Apple (or any other way) how to determine if a eSim device?

Comment: Yes, there is a property  - [supportsEmbeddedSIM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcellularplanprovisioning/4052136-supportsembeddedsim)

Comment: @Paulw11 this return "false" too for me (iPhone with only eSim)

Comment: If your questions is how to know if the device supports eSim without the entitlement from Apple, then the answer is "no"

Answer (score 1):

I expect there is no way to do this directly. The property (`supportsEmbeddedSIM`) is on CTCellularPlanProvisioning, which requires an entitlement. You can't just call `CTCellularPlanProvisioning()`. You need to create a [CTCellularPlanProvisioningRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcellularplanprovisioningrequest), but that's not a general purpose tool:

> This class is only available to carrier apps with suitable entitlements.

You'd need to check the [device model](https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit). eSIM has been supported on [all iPhones since the iPhone XS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212780). (See comments; @sergey_s notes that there are exceptions.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

But, unfortunately, there are devices that only support 2 physical SIM cards (since iPhone 13, it seems). eSim cannot be added to them.

Comment: I expect the only solution will be to enumerate those devices in your code (which unfortunately means updating it as new models come out). I do not believe there is any way to query for this.

Comment: You might also discuss with the maintainer of DeviceKit. They already provide a lot of hand-gathered information per-device (for example `hasLidarSensor`), and may be willing to add this.

Comment: Also, for this kind of thing, it's worth opening a Feedback to Apple, explaining your use case. There likely is no fix (and I doubt they will give you an entitlement), but they may provide new APIs in the future to enable whatever you're trying to do. Best of luck.